# Subsetting strings from a column if they match multiple strings in a different column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I'd like to subset a column to only contain strings that match multiple strings in a different column. Here's some mock data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(species = c("Rufl","Rufl","Soca","Assp","Assp","Elre"),
                  state = c("warmed","ambient","warmed","warmed","ambient","ambient"))
```

I'd like have a dataframe with only species that match both the "warmed" and "ambient" states, removing species that only match one string, so the final dataframe would have "Rufl" and "Assp" with their given states, as shown below

```
species  state
Rufl     warmed
Rufl     ambient
Assp     warmed
Assp     ambient
```

I've tried a few different attempts at this, both with the subset function and dplyr, but can't figure out the right way to get this to work. Here's my failed attempts:

```
df2 <- subset(df1$species, state == "warmed" & state == "ambient")

# or this?
df2 <- df1 %>%
        group_by(species) %>%
        filter(state == "warmed",
               state == "ambient")
```

Thanks for the help!

Using R version 4.0.2, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a group by `all`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(species) %>% 
   filter(all(c('warmed', 'ambient') %in% state)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  species state  
#  <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Rufl    warmed 
#2 Rufl    ambient
#3 Assp    warmed 
#4 Assp    ambient
```

The `&` operation doesn't work as the elements are not present in the same location

---

Or using `subset`

```
subset(df1, species %in% names(which(rowSums(table(df1) > 0) == 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `ave`

```
subset(
  df1,
  ave(state, species, FUN = function(x) sum(c("warmed", "ambient") %in% x)) == 2
)
```

gives

```
  species   state
1    Rufl  warmed
2    Rufl ambient
4    Assp  warmed
5    Assp ambient
```